# Cannot convert a character/string to int

Tags: c++

When I run my code I get this error at compile time:

```
# g++ -std=c++0x sixteen.cpp -O3 -Wall -g3 -o sixteen
sixteen.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sixteen.cpp:10: error: call of overloaded ‘stoi(char&)’ is ambiguous
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2565: note: candidates are: int std::stoi(const std::string&, size_t*, int) <near match>
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2626: note:                 int std::stoi(const std::wstring&, size_t*, int) <near match>
```

I looked up that error and followed the instructions that other questions on here have done, however I still get that error after removing `using namespace std;`. Why is this still happening and what can I do to get rid of it?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string test = "Hello, world!";
    std::string one = "123";

    std::cout << "The 3rd index of the string is: " << test[3] << std::endl;

    int num = std::stoi(one[2]);
    printf( "The 3rd number is: %d\n", num );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string` can't be made from a single `char` argument.

Comment: `int num = std::stoi (&one.c_str ()[2]);` Would work, but only because it is the last non-NULL character in the C string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::stoi` takes a `std::string` as its argument, but `one[2]` is a `char`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the fact that the digit characters are guaranteed to have contiguous values, so you can do:

```
int num = one[2] - '0';
```

Alternatively, you can extract the digit as a substring:

```
int num = std::stoi(one.substr(2,1));
```

And another alternative, you can construct a `std::string` using the constructor that takes a `char` and the number of times that `char` should appear:

```
int num = std::stoi(std::string(1, one[2]));
```

Comment: I always end up forgetting something like that. I've been using weakly typed languages a bit too long now. Thanks!